# Are there any issues with placing castellations on corners of a PCB

Tags: pcb-design

I've had a request from a client for a PCB design with castellations on the corners of the board. The board is not actually rectangular, so the corners are not right-angles but more like this:

[image: Basic drawing of PCB showing castellated pad on an angled corner]

I'd like to know if there are any issues with castellations on PCB corners in general (as opposed to the sides), and with non-right-angled corners specifically.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask your PCB fab, not us, since PCB fabs have varying capabilities. I personally don't see any functionality problem, but function and manufacturability are two different things.

Comment: Yes that is sensible and I will do that - I asked in case there are issues that any board house would have that mean it's not even worth designing the PCB with this feature.